# Tabbed Page without Back button in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms 5 app, I have a settings icon in the footer of my `AppShell` and when clicked, I'm opening up a `TabbedPage`. This part is working fine but when the page opens up, I see the back button at the top. I want this `TabbedPage` to look and behave like any other page in the `FlyoutItem`s section.

Here's the effect I'm trying to create:

[image]

I'm able to create this with the following in my `ShellFooter`:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      x:Class="Ingrid.Connect.Views.FlyoutFooter"
      RowDefinitions="120"
      ColumnDefinitions="150, 150">
    <Image
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        Margin="50,0,0,0">
        <Image.Source>
            <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="MISHRP"
                Glyph="{StaticResource SettingsIcon}"
                Color="White"/>
        </Image.Source>
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="Settings_Tapped" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
    <Image
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        Margin="0,0,30,0">
        <Image.Source>
            <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="MISHRP"
                Glyph="{StaticResource PowerIcon}"
                Color="White"/>
        </Image.Source>
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="LogOut_Tapped" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

And the `Settings_Tapped` method looks like this:

```
async void Settings_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SettingsPage));
}
```

And the `SettingsPage` is simply a `TabbedPage`. This setup works but as I said, I do get the "Back" button at the top of the page. I want the "Settings" page to look and behave just like any other page in the app.

BTW, I tried adding `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(SettingsPage, false);` but this is giving me an error. It reads:

> 'SettingsPage' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Any idea how I can make my `SettingsPage` to look and behave like any other page?

Comment: you need to pass in the instance of `SettingsPage`, not the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other pages are items which are wrapped in ShellContent,if you use GoToAsync, the new page and mainpage will not display on the same layer of the stack.So you can wrap the settingspage and change the currentitem when click the button like:

- in xmal:

  ```
  <FlyoutItem Title="."  IsVisible="False" x:Name="mysettings">
        <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
  ```
- buttonclicked:

  ```
  Shell.Current.CurrentItem=mysettings;
  ```

Comment: I had to modify it a bit but this solution worked. It also showed me I really need to understand navigation much better than I do now.

Here are the changes I made. When I set `<FlyoutItem IsVisible="False"...`, the route is not available. So I used `<FlyoutItem FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"...` instead and this registers the route fine. I then used a standard navigation approach using `Shell.Current.GotoAsync($"///{nameof(SettingsPage)}")`. This works nicely now. Thank you for your help!